# How to specify temporary target in Ansible on debugging?

Tags: ansible

I should re-write question, so I do. > "Not super clear what you're trying to do here."

I'm trying to debugging tasks. On the debugging, I'm targeting temporary host (a host who was created by lxd), and I'd like to want target this host.

**Previous:**

Title: How to specity target on the fly on the modern way in Ansible?

I seem to the aim of Ansible's inventory is to supply fixed target hosts, but I'd like to specify target on the fly in case of debugging. There exists the [Dynamic Inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html), but it's not in case. I'd like to know how to specity target on the fly on the modern way in Ansible?

Comment: I seem to edit my inventory on the fly in easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not super clear what you're trying to do here. If you're attempting to deal with a cloud provider where you have ephemeral hosts, you can use the cloud provider module plus the "add_host" module to essentially build an inventory at run-time (which ensures if you are destroying and rebuilding hosts that you don't need to rebuild your inventory every time). That's what the "Dynamic Inventory" article you linked is meant to address, and it doesn't require and additional scripts to run.

If you're trying to target one or two hosts for debugging (which is what you're "in the case of debugging" comment would suggest), then the "limit" option in ansible is what you're looking for. It allows you to limit to a single group or host when running a playbook.

If you provide more info, I can provide some examples of either method.

Comment: Previous my question is too messy, so I'm cleared the question. I'd like to debug my task and I made lxd host.

Comment: If all you're doing is trying to run the whole playbook against a temporary host, just create a separate inventory file (or a separate group within the same inventory file).

Answer (score 0):

When running `ansible-playbook` run with `--limit` or `-l` for a specific group or host.

If you want to create an **ad-hoc** host during the play, you can use the `add_host` module in your playbooks:

```
- add_host:
    hostname: "{{ new_ip }}"
    ansible_ssh_host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    ansible_ssh_port: "{{ new_port }}"
```